# Arcing through an inductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, inductance

When a current is passed through an inductor coil, potential difference across it is given as $$V=L\frac{dI}{dt} \, .$$
Now, if we suddenly disconnect the coil from the circuit, the current will instantaneously go to zero and potential difference across it would approach infinite as $\frac{dI}{dt}\rightarrow\infty$. This will ionise the surrounding air and sparks will be produced.

My question is that if we repeat the above procedure in vacuum, would the sparks be produced?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't make it clear earlier. It is not that the gas necessarily has to ionise to produce sparks/arc. It can be due to any other factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is that if we repeat the above procedure in vacuum, would
>   the sparks be produced?

Not in perfect vacuum, because there is no gas to ionize. An understanding of this behavior can be attained by studying Paschen's Law (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%27s_law), which describes the breakdown voltage for given distance and pressure.

Comment: Are you saying you can't have an arc in vacuum? Why can't the electrons just leave one electrode, fly through vacuum, and arrive in the other electrode?

Comment: Yes, I am saying that. Because arcing is electrical breakdown of the gas to form a conducting path and produce an ongoing discharge. It is not the same as electron ejection.

Comment: Even if there is no gas to ionise, can't the very high magnitude of electric field pull/eject electrons from the metal conductor of which the inductor coil is made?

Comment: It can, but that would not be considered arcing.